# Gibt es vielleicht einen Unterschied zwischen „wundern“ und „verwundern“

Tags: translation, english-to-german, difference

> Es wunderte mich nicht, dass er zur Party nicht gekommen ist.
>
> Es verwunderte mich nicht, dass er zur Party nicht gekommen ist.

In diesem Kontext und allgemein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt Konstruktionen, da verwendet man nur wundern:

> Ich wundere mich über die Preise.

Mit verwundern muss man den Satz umstellen:

> Die Preise verwundern mich.